# regex pattern to match specific start and end anchors with variable words in between

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to normalize unstructured text files. I can't seem to figure out the expression for matching specific start and end boundaries with any degree of success.

sample texts:

```
"Section 13 - Governmental Oversight and Operational Accountability."
"Section 13 : Governmental Over-sight and Accountability."
"Section 13. Governmental Oversights, Controls and Operational Accountability."
"Section 13.\nGovernmental Oversight\nand Operational Accountability."
```

Given the samples above, I can always expect to find "`Section 13([ \.:-{0,2}])(space|newline)Governmental"` at the beginning and "Accountability" at the end, but there is a large degree of variability in between. I have to repeat this process for about 30 Sections. I parse these documents by iterating the files line by line and sending a 5 line string concatenation into the pattern matcher.

My first attempt was to try to think of every permutation of each sections words, but this proved itself extremely ineffective.

My newest attempt simply doesn't work at all:

```
s13 = lambda t : re.match(r'^(Section(\s{0,})(\n{0,})(\s{0,})13(\.|:?)(\s{0,})(Governmental(\s{0,}.*Accountability)', t, re.I|re.S)
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the `+` operator for your ranges. This seems to do the trick with your sample texts.

```
Section[\s\\n]+13[ -:\\n]+(Governmental.*?Accountability\.)
```

Try the following site to test your regex http://re-try.appspot.com/